# Do not allow duplicate dropdowns

Tags: jquery, forms

I am guessing this is JS or jQuery but I'm not at all fluent with those (just starting to pick them up after many years of PHP).

I have 3 drop down boxes in a form that are all somewhat identical.  All have a list of the same cites that are pulled from a MySQL database and populated via PHP.  Let's say the cities are:

- City 1
- City 2
- ...
- City 8

The default values for the 3 drop downs will be:

- Dropdown 1 is City 1
- Dropdown 2 is N/A
- Dropdown 3 is N/A

Basically I just need to make the drop downs work where a city selected in any of 3 automatically removes it from the other 2 drop downs.  In the end there can be no duplicate entries in the 3 pull down lists.  Also I need it to happen dynamically (onChange event?) so that if they select City 4 in the first list it immediately is removed as an option from the other two drop down lists.

Hopefully this makes sense?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   var selectedVal, $this, valuesToCheck;
$("select").change(function(){
   selectedVal = $(this).val();
   valuesToCheck = [selectedVal];
  $("select").each(function(){
     valuesToCheck.push($(this).val());
     $(this).find("option:disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
  }).each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $.each(valuesToCheck, function(){
            $this.find("option[value='"+this+"']").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What if the user changes their selection? Or uses keyboard to scroll down the list? Each city would be removed from the other selects one after another.

Comment: I agree it will remove but that is what OP's requirement is. We can have some other solution like disabling the options instead of removing it.

Comment: @Chris - I have edited my answer to disable the option instead of removing it take a look.

Comment: @Chris - Please check my eidted answer I ahve added code to disable the options instead of removing them and enabling it again when required.

Comment: Shankar, I think I'm on the right track with yours but I'm afraid I need a bit more of noob help than this...I've created a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pNwBM/ can you look at that?

Comment: @Chris - Take a look at this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pNwBM/2/). I have also edited my answer. It is working now as expected.

Comment: I think its close but if you change the top 2 drop downs, the 3rd just disables the last one selected, not both of the select ones.  Also this looks like it applies to all select entities, would I use a class name to apply it only to these 3 (for example replace "select" with ".mythreedropdowns"?

Comment: Yes you can select the required select dropdowns using class name of ids. It is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/pNwBM/2/. Make sure the ids are unique which you provided in your example.

Comment: Hmmm, on the fiddle you just posted if I select City 2 in the top list, then city 3 in the next one, in the bottom list, only city 3 is disabled,  city 2 is available.  It's as if its only catching the last change, not all of them.  I will "fiddle" with it some more. :-)

Comment: I thought thats what you wanted. Let me change it.

Comment: Shankar, one more question.  The top answer is the default on the first dropdown, is there a way to disable that top answer on the subsequent boxes, since its already selected on the first box?

Comment: I think triggering the change event on first select box will do the trick. Call this `$("select:first").trigger('change')` after the events are attached.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selectBox option[value='option']").remove(); --remove

$("#selectBox").append('<option value="option">option</option>'); --add
```

you can use the .change() to remove the option

```
$("select").change(function(){
  //remove option
})
```

what happens after a city is removed from select1 and select2 and the user changes the value of select3 to a different city, do you add the city back to the list?

Comment: Yes, cities should be added back as needed

Answer (score 0):

And if he change back the value of dropdown 1 ? i guess you will have to put back the value removed?  This would create a lot of ajax call to refresh the content of the other dropdown.  I suggest you validate your condition on the onChange event and display a msg if you detect duplicates.

If you remove the entry like the other repsonse sugest....  if you select all the city 1 by 1 on the first dropdown, you will end up with no more entry in the 2 others ;-)